# Google speed page

Tags: frontend, pagespeed-insights, google-page-speed

У меня задача стоит чтоб сделать данный сайт в зеленой зоне в Google speed page, а сейчас он в красной зоне. Удалила все что возможно, даже анимации. А фото вообще в кб. Скажите как мне исправить это пожалуйста?
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=RU&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffront-up.ru%2Fevakuacia%2F

Answer (score 1):

Если вы прокрутите немного вниз **[указанный результат тестирования](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=RU&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffront-up.ru%2Fevakuacia%2F)**, то там в секции *Возможности оптимизации*, вы можете видеть что первые два места занимают картинки:

> Отложите загрузку скрытых изображений 1,52 s
>
> Используйте современные форматы изображений 1,35 s

Возможно вам надо пересмотреть важность картинок этой веб-страницы. По моему скромному мнению, эта веб-страница не имеет ни одной важной картинки, то есть картинки без которой содержание веб-страницы может быть искажено или не понятно пользователям. Все картинки этой веб-страницы имеют цель украшения, но полность лишены функциональности. Картинки слайдшоу в самом верху имеют текст с нарушение цветового баланса, то есть текст плохо виден на фоне картинок.

Обратите внимание на тот факт, что на мобильных устройствах это слайдшоу загружается в прямом потоке загрузки и для достижения полезной информации пользователю надо критить вниз.

Вы можете анализировать критические ресурсы этой веб-страницы с бесплатным онлайн инструментом **[WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190923_5E_5f78750f7dbb6da79758c84fcd103d6a/)**. Там вы можете видеть три варианта анализа. Выберите вариант с наиболее низкой скоростью загрузки = 12.694 секунды и щелкните на этом варианте.

**[В новом окне вы можете видеть](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190923_5E_5f78750f7dbb6da79758c84fcd103d6a/)** что эта веб-страница имеет **75** запросов внешних ресурсов. Для оптимизации этих ресурсов вы можете пересмотреть их важность и удалить не важные ресурсы.

Проверьте следующие **[результаты тестирования этой веб-страницы на бесплатном инструменте W3C mobileOK Checker](http://mobile.css-validator.org/check?task=2019092306461612&docAddr=http%3A%2F%2Ffront-up.ru%2Fevakuacia%2F)**:

> The total size of the page (618.1KB) exceeds 20 kilobytes (Primary
> document: 36.8KB, Images: 513.9KB, Style sheets: 67.4KB)
>
> The document contains a frame, frameset or iframe element
>
> HTTP status code 404 (Not Found) or 5xx (Server Error) received for an
> embedded resource

Мой перевод:

> Общий размер страницы (618,1 КБ) превышает 20 килобайт (основной
> документ: 36,8 КБ, изображения: 513,9 КБ, таблицы стилей: 67,4 КБ)
>
> Документ содержит элемент frame, frameset или iframe
>
> Код состояния HTTP 404 (не найден) или 5xx (ошибка сервера),
> полученный для встроенного ресурса

Щелкайте на каждом из этих критичных ресурсов и там будет показана вам возможности оптимизации этого.

Проверьте **[невалидный ХТМЛ этой веб-страницы](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ffront-up.ru%2Fevakuacia%2F)**. Это может мешать **[рендерингу](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model)**.

По моему скромному мнению вам надо создавать полностью новую веб-страницу и установить все стили прямо в head. Это устранит вызов внешних стилей.

Удалите все лишние картинки. Оптимальное количество изображений для веб-страницы = 1.

Для оптимизации изображений используйте **[руководство Гугл для отзывчивых изображений](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)**. Для выбора размеров изображений для разных экранов, используйте статью на английском языке **[Применение srcset: выбор правильных размеров для адаптивных изображений в разных точках останова](https://medium.com/hceverything/applying-srcset-choosing-the-right-sizes-for-responsive-images-at-different-breakpoints-a0433450a4a3)**. Для сжатия изображений используйте бесплатный онлайн инструмент **[Compress Image](https://compressnow.com/)**.

Для сжатия исходного кода используйте бесплатный онлайн инструмент **[HTML Compressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/)**.

Также хорошим решение может быть использование **[фреймворка АМП](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/)**, который рекомендует Гугл.